# What does this Perl while loop mean?

Tags: perl, match

```
while ($aaa =~ m/= "(\D.*?)"/g)
```

I figured that it matches while `$aaa` is like `anything = "something"` it returns `something` (without the quotation mark).

But what does this piece of code mean?

```
m/= "(\D.*?)"/
```

Comment: Thanks ysth and blueygh2 for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have figured out most of it.  The `=`, , and `"` all literally match those characters.  The `()` capture a part of the matched string and make it available as `$1`.  The part inside the parenthesis matches a non-digit character (`\D`), followed by zero or more (`*?`) non-newline characters (`.`) until the `"`.  `*` would also match zero or more times, but prefers to match more characters so would end up matching until the last `"` in the string instead of the next one, as `*?` does.

All of this is documented in [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html).

Answer (score 1):

The equals sign and quotation mark are taken literally, `\D` means any non-digit, `.*?` followed or not by zero or more characters, of any kind.

From left to right:

```
m/= "(\D.*?)"/g

match operator, 
start regex: 
  equals sign, whitespace, double quotation mark, 
  start group: 
    one non-digit character, zero or more characters, 
  end group, 
  double quotation mark, 
end regex
match globally
```